# ADDTIME() return 24 hour time

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT ADDTIME(TIME('23:59:59'), TIME('02:00:00'));
```

This currently returns: **'25:59:59'**
I want it to return: **'01:59:59'**

A simple question I know but I just can't find out how to tell MySQL to do this rather than returning at 25 hour time. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if that's the best solution, but it seems to work :

`SELECT TIME((ADDTIME(TIME('23:59:59'), TIME('02:00:00')))%(TIME('24:00:00')));`