# how to add hours ,minutes or seconds in 'TIME' Datatype in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to add hours or minutes in TIME datatype (no DATE in here) in MySQL:

```
create table table1(
    arrival_time TIME
);
```

Here is the case in which the problem is, after `23:59:59` in `arrival_time`, if I add 1 hour , it should display `00:59:59`, not `24:59:59`.

I have tried many functions like `addtime()`, `date_add()` and all but doesn't work with the above requirement.

Comment: This may help http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp

Comment: As per the manual dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time.html the valid range for TIME is from '-838:59:59' to '838:59:59'. Showing 24:59:59 is working correctly even though it is not what you desire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select arrival_time,
       maketime(mod(HOUR(date_add(arrival_time, INTERVAL 1 HOUR)), 24),
                mod(minute(date_add(arrival_time, INTERVAL 2 MINUTE)), 60),
                mod(second(date_add(arrival_time, INTERVAL 2 SECOND)), 60)) sooner_or_later,
       TIME((ADDTIME(TIME('23:59:59'), TIME('01:02:02')))%(TIME('24:00:00'))) or_rather_so
from table1;
```

returns

```
|                   ARRIVAL_TIME |                SOONER_OR_LATER |                   OR_RATHER_SO |
|--------------------------------|--------------------------------|--------------------------------|
| January, 01 1970 23:59:59+0000 | January, 01 1970 00:01:01+0000 | January, 01 1970 01:02:01+0000 |
```

Second column pushing bits. Last column doing proper arithmetic - borrowed from [ADDTIME() return 24 hour time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25655044/addtime-return-24-hour-time?rq=1)

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f095a/10/0)

Answer (score 0):

I have two fields. One field as time_frame with time like

> 01:15

and in second field minutes in number

> 45

This is working for me,

```
( ADDTIME(STR_TO_DATE( appointments.time_frame, "%H:%i:%s" ), STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT( "0", FLOOR( `appointments`.appx_hour / 60 ), ":", MOD ( `appointments`.appx_hour, 60 ),":00" ),"%H:%i:%s" ))) AS total_time
```