# How to add extra 5 minutes in mysql using query

Tags: mysql

I'm new for mysql, Already value in time field, I want to update extra 5 minutes in time field using query. I tried so many things but not working.

Here my query:

```
UPDATE STUDENT SET START_TIME = ADDTIME(START_TIME, 500) WHERE ID = 1;
```

Above query working but one issue is there that is, If my field having 23:55:00.
I want result after executing query 00:00:00 but it updates 24:00:00.

Anyone help me!

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What type is the `START_TIME` column?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  Time type

Answer (score 0):

This is bit tricky, because you only have the time, and you want it to wrap around to 0 after hitting 24 hours.  My approach is to extract the number of seconds from `START_DATE`, add 5 minutes, then take the mod of this by 24 hours to wrap around to zero if it exceeds one day's worth of seconds.

```
UPDATE STUDENT
SET START_TIME = CAST(STR_TO_DATE(CAST(MOD((TIME_TO_SEC(START_TIME) + 300), 86400) AS CHAR(5)), '%s') AS TIME)
WHERE ID = 1
```

In the demo below, you can see the logic in action which correctly converts `23:55:00` with five minutes added to become `00:00:00`.

## SQLFiddle

However, the easiest solution in your case might be to just use a `DATETIME` and ignore the date component.  Then the time should wrap automatically to a new day.

Comment: `It's not working perfectly` ... this doesn't let me help you

Answer (score 0):

select addtime('23:55:00', '00:06:00');

output - 24:01:00 (Ideally it is right, because time datatype represents only time, if it converts to 00:01:00 then time component looses 24hr, which is wrong)

select addtime('2016-09-01 23:55:00', '00:06:00');

output - 2016-09-02 00:01:00 (In this case, 24hr gets added in date so time component is represented as 00:01:00)

If the requirement is to get it as 00:01:00 then here is the workaround -

**SELECT TIME((ADDTIME(TIME('23:59:59'), TIME('02:00:00')))%(TIME('24:00:00')));**

reference -

[ADDTIME() return 24 hour time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25655044/addtime-return-24-hour-time?rq=1)